# Powershell build Script run from Jenkins can't find msbuild, even though path added to system path variable

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have a PowerShell script that executes msbuild that gets called by a Jenkins job.  In that script, we append to the system path variable the path to Visual Studio and msbuild in 3 different locations:

- Enterprise (needed for SonarQube builds)
- Community Edition (needed for other build agents)
- Build Tools (newest Jenkins agent)

When the script is called running on the new agent from a Jenkins job, it errors with this:

```
FATAL: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin doesn't exist
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
That folder path does not exist on the new agent. The msbuild exe resides in the Visual Studio Build Tools folder path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin), not the Community edition folder path.
```

When I manually run the script from the agent, with or without the path variable, it runs fine.

**Steps Tried:**

- Manually added the path on the new VM to the system environment PATH variable and still get the same error when running the script from Jenkins.
- Commented out the lines that add the path for the Community edition and pushed a release that ran on new agent. That errored differently:

```
    & : The term 'msbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

- Manually added the folder path for the Community edition to the system environment PATH variable on the agent and still got the same error when pushed via PR.

**Research:**

- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-3632 indicates that this is a known issue with the MSBuild Jenkins plug-in in versions up to 1.3 and was fixed in 1.4.
- If you go here, https://plugins.jenkins.io/msbuild/#releases, the latest release seems only be 1.3!?!?!
  Also noted that plugin only seems to apply to actual build steps created in Jenkins, not scripts that call msbuild (but it is affecting our script when called from Jenkins)

Does anyone know if build 1.4 exists anywhere and where it can be downloaded?

Comment: Have you tried both restarting the agent and if that did not work, restarting the master? Jenkins seems to cache all these env settings somewhere.

Comment: Yep, didn't help.

Comment: The laterst release is 1.30 (+26 from 1.4). See [plugins repository](https://plugins.jenkins.io/msbuild/#dependencies) and  [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/msbuild-plugin/releases). I see it in the `/pluginManager`; requires J 2.222.1+. Your issue referenced is over 10 yrs old! Although it was also reported 6 yrs ago in 1.25, but the issue was not reopened.